# How do I paste graphic at specific place in flash movie clip?

Tags: flash, adobe, registration, paste, movieclip

I know this is not a question about code, but I thought asking it here would be wise anyway, since people here know flash.

I'm making a platform game character in adobe flash. I want her to be able to walk towards the left, towards the right, kick, jump etc.. This requires me to paste different image files in each frame.

I want the file to be placed just above the registration point (I specified this when I made the movie clip also). But when I paste it, it just keeps appearing at random places.

Ive seen people on youtube paste the graphic right at the right place, without having to move it afterwards, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the registration points when creating a movieclip or graphic it will show you a small grid from memory... looks like below image

[image: regopoint]

The images will snap to here either from what you choose, this is also the objects rotational point aswell...

To control it place x,y  it better add a movieclip inside of a empty movieclip and change the second clip to where you want inside the first and past inside there....